# What's the "proper" IP / network calculation module in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, network-programming, ip

Since "The Zen of Python" tells us "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it." I would like to ask what is the best upstream module to use for IP and/or network calculations?

I found the following:

- **ipcalc** - which seems to be maintained no more (bug issues open for >2 years)
- **netaddr** - which seems to do exactly what I want and has a great documentation (I'm using this one at the moment)
- **ipaddress** - which seems to have more or less the same functionality as netaddr (but with a more clumsy interface, telling from documentation)
- **ipaddr** - which may be something like that telling from the few words on the github repo (can't seem to find a real documentation)

Maybe there are even more?
I would really like to know what the community thinks is the best way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May not be the best, but **ipaddress** is part of [The Python Standard Library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html), so it would be definitely my first choice.

Comment: I actually asked for the "most common" way, not necessarily the best.
So this is exactly the answer I wanted to hear. Thanks. :)